# Поиск сайтов на конкретном wordpress шаблоне

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли возможность найти сайты, сделанные на определенном `wordpress` шаблоне?

Comment: То, что это не лохотрон не гарантирую:  
http://ru.publicwww.com/  
Если это Ваш шаблон, то нужно было закладочку делать. Например выводить  уникальный текст цветом совпадающий с фоном, а потом его искать в гугле

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать поискать картинки используемые в шаблоне. (Google дает возможность загрузить/указать URL картинки для поиска идентичных и похожих).

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. 
Только нужно угадать название папки на сервере, куда кладется этот шаблон.
Например, мне нужно было найти сайты, сделанные на шаблоне "Event Time". 
Я предположил, что название папки будет eventtime (и оказался прав)). 
Дальше забиваем в гугл:

allinurl:"wp-content" eventtime

И вылетает определенное количество ссылок на страницы сайтов на этом шаблоне.
А дальше из ссылки берется собственно домен - и на нем оказывается этот сайт.

Есть также сервис https://publicwww.com - но он уже за деньги.